# Send keystrokes to powerpoint windows

Tags: python, powerpoint, pywin32, win32com, win32gui

I'm trying to send keystrokes to a PowerPoint slideshow in Python, in order to advance the slideshow automatically. I would like to send the `VK_RIGHT` and `VK_LEFT` messages.

I'm using `win32gui.FindWindow` to find the Powerpoint window by its title, then try to send message to the window handle with :

```
win32api.SendMessage(windowhandle, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RIGHT, 0))
```

While this works for other applications like Notepad, it doesn't seem to work on the main window. For Notepad it works actually on its child window, so I've tried with Powerpoint children windows :

```
win32gui.EnumChildWindows
```

and I cycle them to send the same message to every child window, but it doesn't seem to work either.

The `LRESULT` of the `win32api.SendMessage` is always 0 (it is 1 with the Notepad).

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and probably better) solution would be to use COM32, which happens to be included in win32api.

You can use [this library for office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/reference-object-library-reference-for-office) for reference.

An Example to open up a powerpoint and view the next slide:

```
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
objCOM = app.Presentations.Open(FileName="path_to_file", WithWindow=1)
objCOM.SlideShowWindow.View.Next()
```

Source: https://medium.com/@chasekidder/controlling-powerpoint-w-python-52f6f6bf3f2d

Comment: Thank you @OskarZyg. I actually already saw the medium article and tried this approach. It misses one step, in the sense that you have to start the slide show first (I don't know how to do it). 
But most importantly, I have to control the window of a presentation which would be broadcast online, not the one with the traditional slideshow window. I don't understand if this library covers this "rare" feature.
So to me as of now the best option would still be to send keyboard inputs to the slideshow window.

Comment: There actually seems to be a broadcast model in that library :

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.broadcast)

I might give a try to this

Comment: The broadcast object is ill-documented. While I can start a slideshow locally, the broadcast asks for a serverUrl. Whatever URL I try to give it, it doesn't work.
The Office Presentation Service is actually supposed to give you back the presentation URL, at least that's what happens when you start broadcasting a slideshow in the powerpoint desktop app.